# Latex or doxygen plugin for Clion

Tags: clion

This is found in the comment section of one of the opencv source headers. The language looks latex to me within doxygen. I am using CLion and is it possible to expand this in readable format by using a plugin?

```
/** @brief  Checks if array elements lie between the elements of two other arrays.
The function checks the range as follows:
-   For every element of a single-channel input array:
    \f[\texttt{dst} (I)= \texttt{lowerb} (I)_0  \leq \texttt{src} (I)_0 \leq  \texttt{upperb} (I)_0\f]
-   For two-channel arrays:
    \f[\texttt{dst} (I)= \texttt{lowerb} (I)_0  \leq \texttt{src} (I)_0 \leq  \texttt{upperb} (I)_0  \land \texttt{lowerb} (I)_1  \leq \texttt{src} (I)_1 \leq  \texttt{upperb} (I)_1\f]
-   and so forth.
*/
```

Comment: Clion should already be able to render doxygen inline. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-and-viewing-doxygen-documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it’s possible with some limitations (please note that at the moment CLion doesn’t provide a public API).

Seems for your purpose you can write your own small “injected language” and then introduce it into the comment body.

Here’s a tutorial which describes [“how to write a simple language for Intellij IDEA”](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html). Please note for your purpose you can implement only lexer, parser and highlighter.

Using language injector you can “inject” your language to comment body. 
More information you can find here:

- [LanguageInjector](https://github.com/joewalnes/idea-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/psi/LanguageInjector.java)
- LanguageInjector extension-point: `<languageInjector implementation="com.YourLatexCommentLanguageInjector"/>`
- Also possibly you need to override the standard comment type, see [`com.intellij.core.CoreASTFactory#createComment`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-impl/src/com/intellij/core/CoreASTFactory.java)

And also you can [write your own QuickDocumentationProvider](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/documentation.htm) and try to render latex in quick documentation popup as you wish.